# input from multiple pipes

Tags: bash, pipe

How pass arguments from multiple pipes?

```
command1 | command2 outputOfcommand1 | command3 outputOfcommand1  outputOfcommand2
```

What I trying to do more specifically is to list some directory inside container, get last created file and pull to the host machine. Now I use

```
sudo ls -t /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/containers/con1/rootfs/home/usr1/Downloads | head -n 1 | xargs -I{} sudo mv /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/containers/con1/rootfs/home/usr1/Downloads/{} .
```

. The path showed up here 2 times and I want to decrease it to one apperaing.

Comment: Are `outputOfcommand1` and `outputOfcommand2` supposed to be _strings_ consisting of the output of the two first commands (in which case using a pipeline does not make sense), or do you use these as placeholders meaning e.g. "read output from `command1` from standard input"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you need is command substitution, not pipes:

```
outputOfcommand1=$(command1)
outputOfcommand2=$(command2 "$outputOfcommand1")
command3 "$outputOfcommand1"  "$outputOfcommand2"
```

Comment: See update to the question.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However I have to use sudo so still need pipes for some part. Now I do ` a=$(echo "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/containers/con1/rootfs/home/usr1/Downloads"); sudo ls -t $a | head -n 1 | xargs -I{} sudo mv $a/{} . `